# Does Linux implement page coloring?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Does the current Linux kernels implements some form of page coloring when assigning virtual to physical address mapping?

Arka

Comment: The question is _not_ unclear. Is the poster really obliged to put a link to a google search for "page coloring" into the question ? The term has a very precise a technical meaning.

Comment: Indeed the question is quite clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Linus [said](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/cache_coloring.html):

> there have been at least four different major cache coloring trials
>   for the kernel over the years. This discussion has been going on since the
>   early nineties. And *none* of them have worked well in practice.

[Reasons are](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/page_coloring.html) that it adds too much cost to the page free/page alloc paths, and it's pointless
because caches have become associative so that there is no need.